# Modernizr + YepNope: doesn't load my external jQuery?

Tags: jquery, modernizr, yepnope

The situation is simple: I'm using the Bones framework for Wordpress. If I put the jQuery in the scripts.js file, they run fine. Everything works. If try loading the the jQuery calls ONLY if a yep or nope is satisfied, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

script.js

```
// Modernizr.load loading the right scripts only if you need them
Modernizr.load([
    {
    // Let's check something simple
    test : Modernizr.borderradius,
    // this should then satisfy the yep and load this script
    yep : ['libs/jq-desk-calls.js']
    }
]);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // if I put the code from jq-desk-calls.js here, it works fine
}
```

I'm using a simple test to make sure it should fire the yep. But nothing happens. The file it's calling is just the code that I can use in the document.ready call and works fine. Does it have to do with calling document.ready from an outside file?

jq-desk-calls.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //LOGO ROLL
    $('li#menu-item-477').append('<div class="emblemhover"></div>');
}
```